# Three.js Material combine Parameter

Tags: three.js, webgl

what is the meaning of

> combine: THREE.MixOperation

in this material definition

```
"shiny"  :
        {
            m: new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x550000, specular: 0x440000, envMap: reflectionCube, combine: THREE.MixOperation, reflectivity: 0.3, metal: true } ),
            h: 0, s: 0.9, v: 0.3
        },
```

this example found here [mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_marching_cubes.html](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_marching_cubes.html)

i have searched alot for documentation and found nothing ?
and if there is any resource i can read about all material parameters will be great help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `THREE.MixOperation` for a material's `combine` parameter, then the `reflectivity` parameter controls how much of the environment map's color is blended with the material's color.

```
gl_FragColor.xyz = mix( gl_FragColor.xyz, cubeColor.xyz, specularStrength * reflectivity );
```

( In this case, `specularStrength` = 1.0 )

The only docs are [these](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/docs/), which are far from complete.

The best thing to do is to read the code.

three.js r.55